# Single and Double backslashes in Python for file paths in Python

Tags: double, openpyxl

I am currently using python module from openpyxl import load_workbook.

I have set a variable for my path:-

```
Report= "C:\Python\Reports\File.xlsx"
```

I then used the code to load the file:-

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=Report)
```

But i kept getting an error, i amended my path to include 2 x backslashes i.e.:-

```
Report= "C:\\Python\\Reports\\File.xlsx"
```

Now it works.

Can anyone explain the difference between single and double backslashes in Python for file paths.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the string you created:

```
>>> print("C:\\Python\\Reports\\File.xlsx")
C:\Python\Reports\File.xlsx
```

As you can tell, the double-backslashes have been replaced with single-backslashes. That's because backslashes in Python (and in many other programming languages) are what's known as an [Escape Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Let's say you want to print `Harry said "Hello!"`. If you try

```py
print("Harry said "Hello!"")
```

you'll run into a problem, because Python will think the quotes mark the end of the string. Thus, python interprets `\"` as a single `"` within a string. But then you also need a way to type `\`, which Python uses `\\` for.

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (scroll down a bit) provides a complete list of the string literals, including the `\\` you discovered.